# Smallest and Largest Eigenvalues of a PSD Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For $M\succeq 0$ and $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, we know the following facts:

1. $$\lambda_{\min} = \min_{\|x\|=1} x^TMx$$
2. $$\lambda_{\max} = \max_{\|x\|=1} x^TMx$$

> My questions are the following:
>    1. Do the above facts hold for **any** square matrices $M\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, or does this matrix have to be at least symmetric?
>    2. Are  the above facts equivalent to "$\|x\|=1$, $x\in \text{span}(M)$"? i.e., we restrict the condition $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ to $x\in \text{span}(M)$

where $\text{span}(M)$ represents the subspace expanded by the column vectors of $M$.

Comment: The objective functional might not even make sense for any square matrices $M$ I think.

Comment: Such results should hold if you replace eigenvalue by singular value (which happen to coincide for PSD matrices). See [these notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/book-chapter-4.pdf), and in particular theorem 1.7 . Note that some modification is necessary - general square random matrices may have complex eigenvalues, in which case $\lambda_\max$ ceases to have any meaning. For general symmetric matrices, assume $\lambda_\min <0.$ Then you could invoke the above results for, say, $A - 2\lambda_{\min} I$ to derive the expressions you desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question does not have an answer since an arbitrary matrix can possess nonreal eigenvalues and equations (1) and (2) above are meaningless in this context.

However, even if we adjust the question, the answer is 'no'. Given $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, the *field (of values) of $A$* (also called the *numerical range of $A$*), is defined by 
$$
F(A) = \{ z^*Az\mid z^*z = 1\}.
$$
It is well-known that $F(A)$ is compact (easy to prove), $\sigma(A) \subseteq F(A)$ (easy to prove), and convex (nontrivial; known as the [Hausdorff-Toeplitz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range#Properties)).

For $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, let $\rho_{\min}(A) := \min\{\lambda \mid \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$ and $\rho_\max(A) := \max \{\lambda \mid \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$. Is it the case that
\begin{equation}
\rho_\min(A) = \min\{ |x| \mid x \in F(A) \} \tag{$\ast$}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\rho_\max(A) = \max\{ |x| \mid x \in F(A) \}? \tag{$\ast\ast$}
\end{equation}

The answer is 'no'. The *elliptical range theorem* states that the field of a two-by-two matrix is a (possibly degenerate) elliptical disk. In particular, if 
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then $F(A)$ is an elliptical disk with foci at $a$ and $c$ and minor-axis length $|b|$.

For example, the field of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & i \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is given by:
[image: Example of F(A)]

From the picture, it is clear that $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$ do not hold.